# How to debug errors on site running on Magento?

Tags: magento

I came to work this morning. The main site is down. The person that work on it is on vacation. 
The site is running on Magento. I'm not familiar with Magento at all.

I think I can do something - if I got some suggestions.

I have the log-in for the admin.
But after I logged in the error message is also there as well. 
I can't really do much.

Is this an easy fix for Magento newbie like me ? :( I'm being honest.
Is there anything that I can do at this moment to bring this site back up ?

I really appreciate your help.

`Exact Error Message`

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'biossusa_Magento.catalog_category_flat_store_1' doesn't exist
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(63033): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(52715): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(53751): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#4 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(54587): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#5 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(53061): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat.php(1314): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(6992): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->checkId('2')
#8 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category.php(74): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category->checkId('2')
#9 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer.php(255): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category->getStoreCategories()
#10 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(21066): Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer->addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(21045): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer), 'addCatalogToTop...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/website/public_html/store/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#13 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu.php(62): Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#14 /home/website/public_html/store/app/design/frontend/default/grayscale/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(48): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
#15 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3223): include('/home/website/...')
#16 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3254): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#17 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3268): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(13181): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2237): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2181): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
#23 /home/website/public_html/store/app/design/frontend/default/grayscale/template/page/html/header.phtml(62): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
#24 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3223): include('/home/website/...')
#25 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3254): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#26 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3268): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2237): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2181): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#30 /home/website/public_html/store/app/design/frontend/default/grayscale/template/page/1column.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#31 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3223): include('/home/website/...')
#32 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3254): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#33 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(3268): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(27414): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#36 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(13574): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#37 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(10934): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#38 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(10849): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#39 /home/website/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#40 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(13603): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#41 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(17948): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#42 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(17505): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#43 /home/website/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php(20082): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#44 /home/website/public_html/store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#45 /home/website/public_html/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#46 {main}
```

Comment: Reindex your site - specifically the Category Flat Data index.

Comment: @Muk : How do I do that ? I am new to Magento. Do you mind answer it with more details information ?

Comment: Do you know how to use SSH or run a script in Magento root using FTP?

Comment: Yes. I know how to use SSH. I also know FTP, and I used to run a script before.

Comment: Go to /shell , directory and run following command                     php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_category_flat

Comment: @Muk : Thanks for your efforts. Is there anything else that I need to do after `php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_category_flat`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66931/discussion-between-muk-and-iggy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reindex your site so that catalog flat table is generated :
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-indexing  will explain steps

else

2. switch flat category to off(in case you are not able to reindex catalog flat category)